# How do I make my phone the device to use for two-factor authentication with the new OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, security

The new OneDrive released in April, 2012 allows you to view files on other devices, even if they are not uploaded to your OneDrive cloud folder.  To enable this, you must use two-factor authentication.  I tried it out, and it sent the authentication request to an old email address that I can't even set anywhere on the Microsoft Live website.

How can I remove this old email address and use my phone as the authentication device?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about using the phone as an authentication device, but I've found how to change your alternative e-mail address. Perhaps you can configure your phone there too?

- Go to [**Windows Live Account**](http://account.live.com) in your browser.
- Type your Windows Live password.
- Under **Account security**, click on **Manage** next to *Security Info*.
- Under **Alternate email address** you can change your alternate e-mail addresses.

Comment: Looks like you can add a mobile device there, and I already have.  There's nothing I can find that lets you set your mobile device as the primary two-factor authentication medium.

Comment: @cowgod: Is your mobile number [listed here](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/my) in the left side? [This page](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/find) asked me to fill it in, it might be that this phone number is shared across the other service. Or perhaps you have to do something on your phone, but getting your number to appear there as well might help. I suppose the SkyDrive settings don't really have any options on this?